# ADO.NET EF what is the purpose of using List<> in the entities

Tags: code-first, ado.net-entity-data-model

Right now I'm learning `ADO.NET Entity Framework` and there's one thing that I can't explain to myself. Here is a source code from a tutorial I've been using recently:

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public User UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```

First I thought that the using of `List<>` is the way to implement Foreign Key-like behaviour but now knowing that's not the case why we need and for what purpose we use `List<>` in our entites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that Blog have a lot of Posts, when you will build your project in DB will be the relation 1xBlog--->NxPost where N=unlimited. This will show that each `Blog` can have unlimited amount of `Post`s

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you help me with that too - `public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }` what represents this?

Comment: This represents that you have for one Post only one Blog

Comment: I'm I right to say that this - `public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }` and this - `public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }` are two parts of one thing which is representing a relation `1 to many`?  In other words does the one part have meaning without the other? Thanks.

Comment: So the result what will heppen if you will run this code. The compiler will look to your `Blog` entity and find that you say that the Blog have a lot of `Post`s. Then He will look to the Post entity and found that you have only one `Blog` for your `Post`. So in the DB will be relation 1xBlog-->NxPost. In linq it will looks like that :

Post post = new Post();
Blog blog = post.Blog;

and through the `Blog`:
Blog blog = new Blog();
List<Post> postsOfThisBlog = blog.Posts;

Comment: I Think one part will work without other part, but in the code in your entity you cant access another entity. But I'm not sure that it will work. You should declare the relations from the both parts to let all work normally.

Comment: Thanks, one last question if you see it - `public int BlogId { get; set; }` is automatically made my `FK` but' it's not programmed anywhere that this is the `FK` for the `Blogs` table. Is this some convention or what is behind getting automatically `BlogId` for my `FK`?

Comment: It is the foreign key in the DB which helps your DB to understend to which Blog your Post is connected. Notice that if you will write not `BlogId` but `blogId` or `BloggId` that will not works. Because there is a rule in the code to use variable name EntityName+Id, otherwise you will have to write mapping in which you will have to show that your `BloggId` or `blogId` is a foreign key for relation Blog-->Post